# Loading jQuery and own JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've looked for some time on the internet to get the right awnser for my problem and asked some colleagues... I'm still at the same problem.

As follows:
(I'm new at using JS and jQuery)

I wanna load my own JS into my HTML (written in PHP).

```
<script src="standaard.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

**standaard.js** contains all of this: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js

**test.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").fadeOut("slow");
    });
});
```

and the `<button>` it refers to is in a PHP file:

```
<button id="button"> CLICK HERE!</button>
```

Now when I just load **standaard.js** and copy the contents of **test.js** in the PHP file between `<script></script>`, it works just as it should.

But when I load it from different files, it doesn't and when I inspect the page in Firefox console it gives me this:

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'
>   [More Info]
>   test.js:4:10

I hope someone could help me with this and that I didn't make a newbie mistake :)

Note: I suspect that it has something to do with time that both scripts need to load and that **test.js** goes first... but then again, I don't get the error that pops up.

**EDIT:**

Here is the trimmed PHP file:

```
<?php

echo        '<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Opdracht 4!</title>
        <meta name="author" content="Danny">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "basis.css">
    </head>
        <body>
            <h3>Naam</h3>
                <p> Danny </p><br>
            <h3>Geboortedatum</h3>
                <p>a date</p><br>
            <h3>Woonplaats</h3>
                <p>A City</p> 

<br><br><br>

    <div class="footer">
        <footer>
            &#169 2017, Danny 
        </footer>
    </div>

        <script src="standaard.js"> </script>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>';
?>
```

Comment: why do you copy the content of jQuery in another file?

Comment: A `SyntaxError` is a parsing error and not a run-time error. So you have a syntactical error in your `test.js` file. The code you show here, would not result in the given error message.

Comment: @messerbill, to check if the standaard.js file does what it has to do & my syntax works.

Comment: ~off-topic, I'd recommend using filenames which say something about the file itself. in this case `jquery.min.js` , just a suggestion

Comment: Did you copy all contents to standaard.js from the jquery file? You might have missed the last closing chars?

Comment: No, when i only copy test.js to the php file and load standaard.js as shown, it actually works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tries I've found the solution! 
It seems quit simple and not very logic but i replaced all " to ' and it worked!?

like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('p').fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

Thank you all for your response, with your help I knew what things to cross off that coulndn't be it.

Answer (score 0):

right before the ending `</body>` tag, put your two scripts in this order:

```
 <script id="jquery" src="standaard.js"></script> 
  and 
 <script src="test.js"></script>
```

You can remove `id="jquery"`. That is not serving any purpose. You should probably just rename the file to be `jquery.min.js`. This is not causing you any real issue, but it makes more sense naming-wise.

in the `test.js` file, you can put your script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").fadeOut("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: This is what the OP states they've already done, bar the placing of the `<script>` before `</body>`, but that's irrelevant as they are using a document.ready handler. Also note that `id` attributes on `script` tags do occasionally have uses (eg. templating) although I agree in this case it's not needed.

Comment: It is a **SyntaxError** so the loading order is not the reason for that error.

Comment: Yeah, he/she did get a syntax error, but there is no syntax error in the `js` that he/she posted. Also, never said anything about loading scripts in body tag

Comment: thanks for respons, the id was a thing that i tried to make it work my bad. Just as you said, it should work but i keeps giving me an error, even when i put the scripts right before the </body>

Comment: Note that the `$("button")` selector is selecting all buttons and not only `#button`

Comment: @Brainfeeder for now it doesnt matter, im just testing to see if I can get it to work.

Comment: Okay :) just in case... The code you posted here is exactly the same as in test.js? because at line 4 the script errors out, but the script in the question is indeed correct.

Comment: Yes, that's why it is making me crazy. I have no idea what the problem could be.. :(

Comment: Maybe you could paste the entire code from both files. the `php` file and `test.js`

Comment: the above code is all from test.js.  I just started working with js after php/oop/mvc. I'll post the php file (trimmed a lot so it's more relevant)

Comment: just a FYI, you don't need to enclose `HTML` within the `PHP` tags like that and `echo` it out, just because it is a `php` file. You can simply delete those `<?php ?>` tags and write plain `HTML` inside `PHP` files.

Comment: Also, you may try removing the script for `standaard.js` and replace it with this: `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: @NateBeers I was about to post the same thing. That would be my first suggestion.